# How to increase the protein content in fish balls?

Tags: fish, nutrient-composition

One of my recipes is [fish balls](http://www.food.com/recipe/fish-balls-527787). My question is how would you increase the protein content of it without affecting the taste?

I have very little sense of taste/smell and when I made it, it had the consistency of mashed potatoes.

Comment: A link to the recipe would be helpful.

Comment: What does smell and taste has anything to do with protein content ?

Comment: @Max perhaps the point is that the OP doesn't care if it tastes or smells good?

Comment: Actually @catija I lost most of my sense of taste and smell due to sinus infections in my childhood.

Comment: You could try an [alternative style](https://rasamalaysia.com/how-to-make-fish-balls/) of fish balls with more fish and less potato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will change the flavor, you know, since anything you add will alter the recipe - even things with very neutral flavors will dilute other tastes.  I'm guessing you want to not alter it much, encourage a similar flavor profile, or add things more neutral in flavor.

A few simple options - you can up the egg content (two eggs instead of one), as eggs have a high percent protein and there's one already in the recipe, so the flavor shouldn't change much (this might give you a bit firmer texture, your call on if that's a plus or not).  You could lower the amount of potato (or up the amount of cod), so the percent of cod is higher in each ball.  You could make a protein-rich sauce to pour on top (depending on what sauce or seasoning you usually use with it).

Alternately - you might try adding some protein powder (most of the ones I see are sweetened, so be careful).  You might look for TVP or TSP (textured vegetable or soy protein) - which is *very* neutral in flavor and also quite inexpensive.  I would recommend crushing to a powder before re-hydrating - this can be done with mortar and pestle, blender, or grinder, whatever you have - or blending afterward to minimize the texture change if you don't like it.  You might add the tvp paste to the mix outright or substitute some reconstituted tvp paste (mixed with water or milk) for part of the mashed potato for a higher ratio of protein to carb.

Comment: What about two egg whites instead of one whole egg?

Comment: @Erica - It's possible, but I didn't recommend it because there would be a much bigger flavor profile difference, I would think.  The yolks change the flavor a lot, and the addition of fats, emulsifiers, etc might change the recipe chemically.  On the other hand, one egg and one white, or even one egg and two whites, might be additional workable combos (since the whites are milder in flavor).

Answer (score 1):

Protein content per 100g: 63g

The recipe calls for 1/2 pound of Cod. So about 140g of per 1/2 pound of Cod.

Which is quite good IMO.

IMO, 1/2 pound cod to 2-1/2 cups of potatoes will make cod-flavoured potato balls.

How will your serve the fish balls ?

Comment: 63% protein by weight sounds extremely high for any dish, even surpassing a lot of straight meat ....

Comment: that was from a quick google, going on further, the protein content for Cod is between 20-something to 60-something grams per portion.

Comment: straight as is after cooking, why @Max

Comment: well, if you want to add more protein, you could add something in the sauce or something like that.

Comment: Your data comes from https://www.nutritionvalue.org/Fish%2C_dried_and_salted%2C_Atlantic%2C_cod_nutritional_value.html which is "Fish, dried and salted, Atlantic, cod". Any living (or freshly dead) animal is 80% water.